# What code to prevent repeat items in random list MIT App Inventor

Tags: list, random, app-inventor

I'm trying to select a random item from a list but after several button taps and I get repeat items and sometimes the same item comes up two or three times in a row. What code can I use to stop repeating items in list unless the complete list has been run through?

Here's my code:
[Random item in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7sYo.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[How to pick a random item from a list without picking duplicates?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2removerandom)

In this example I use the `random integer` block instead of the `pick a random item` block. The picked item will be removed from the list after displaying it.

[image]

Comment: Instead of saying "Thank you" see here [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You also might want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn, how Stackoverflow works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use random shuffle algorithm to initially sort your list with some random key and after that iterate through the sorted list - all the items will be pseudo-random. The wiki article that has more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle